# Using a different normal for shadows and shading

Tags: shaders, normals, shadows

I'm using modified vertex normals for making an anime-style toon shading. The thing is, if an object is placed between the light source and the object with modified normals, it's shadow hasn't got it's actual shape. Is there a way to use a separate normal for just shadows[image]
You can see in this image that the shadow is "wobbly" and it's not the shape it should be.

Edit: Nevermind, I found that the sun type of shader does not work very well with toon shaders and edited vertexd normals, changing the lamp type to area makes it work fine.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you mean by “hasn’t got its actual shape” - preferably add some images to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: Done. I hope this helps!

Comment: Please also add details of how you have set up your normals and how changing the normals affects the shadow (could show with normals 'enabled' and 'disabled' to show a difference). Presumably this is using Eevee...? Please provide as much information as you can to allow someone else to easily replicate your problem.

Comment: Nevermind, i was using a sun type of lamp that doesn't work very well with toon shaders, specially if you edit the vertex normals.

Comment: changing the type of lamp to area makes it work fine

Comment: Glad you’ve solved it. It would be good if you could write a quick answer to your own question so that others can learn from your experience.